# Functions from $[E_8]$ to $E_8$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f: [E_8] \to [E_8]$ be a function between 4-manifolds with intersection form $E_8$. What we know (due to Rocklin) is that $[E_8]$ can't have any smooth structure. Questions:

- Is it true for all the $f$'s that $f$ can be continuous but it can never be a $C^\infty$-function. If not, why ?
- Are there studies being done in function theory of non-smoothable manifolds ? (in my studies, I come across some examples of non-differentiable functions, but they are always somewhat pathological. Hard to imagine a thing where all functions are non-differentiable.
- There is a difference between nowhere and piecewise differentiable, could my $f$ be piecewise differentiable ?

Comment: I think you're getting a bit ahead of yourself.  What would a it mean for a function to be $C^{\infty}$ on a manifold without a smooth structure?

Comment: Callus's point also applies to the third question, as the $E_8$ manifold doesn't admit a PL structure either.

Comment: @Callus: Of course you are right: Being $C^\infty$ or $PL$ does need such a structure in a manifold. There is another question: Are there studies of continuous functions between $E_8$ and $E_8$ ?

Comment: Only answering because the question is directed at me, but my answer is that I don't know of any.  As far as I know, its primary interest is in the obstructions it presents.  In that way, it's a good concrete object to study for the same reason as, say, the Cantor set is an interesting subset of the reals.  But, hopefully somebody else can answer.